# Changing colours and frames in autoplot

Tags: r, ggfortify

I have a dataframe with treatments made in two distinct years ("treat.year" column) and some environmental variables. I want to make a scatterplot of a PCA but I can't figure out how to change the colours of the points.

I want the points in a given treatment (C or Ca) to be the same colour in both sampling periods (e.g. all the C points blue, and all the Ca points, green irrespective of the year) and the "frames" to connect the points according to the treatments AND year (i.e. a frame connecting only C.2009 points, another only C.2015 points and so on).

```
ex <- data.frame(treat.year = c("C.2015", "C.2015", "C.2015", "C.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "C.2009", "C.2009", "C.2009", "C.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009"),
                 var.b = c(33, 18, 34, 28, 12, 11, 15, 13, 45, 52, 35, 39, 29, 27, 30, 27),
                 var.e = c(1.1, 0.5, 1.3, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06, 0.96, 1.06, 0.58, 0.1, 0, 0, 0),
                 var.g = c(83.2, 53.6, 94.9, 80.8, 25.6, 29.2, 31.9, 29.8, 102.3, 83.9, 158.7, 126.6, 78.5, 186.9, 82.4, 62))

PCA1 <- prcomp(ex[ , 2:4], scale = TRUE)

library(ggfortify)
autoplot(PCA1, data = ex, colour = "treat.year", loadings = TRUE, 
         loadings.label = TRUE, frame = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It`s better if you separate "treat.year" in two colums. Then you can change the colours separatly

```
ex <- data.frame(treat.year = c("C.2015", "C.2015", "C.2015", "C.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "Ca.2015", "C.2009", "C.2009", "C.2009", "C.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009", "Ca.2009"),
                treat = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca"),
                 year = c("2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009"),
                 var.b = c(33, 18, 34, 28, 12, 11, 15, 13, 45, 52, 35, 39, 29, 27, 30, 27),
                 var.e = c(1.1, 0.5, 1.3, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06, 0.96, 1.06, 0.58, 0.1, 0, 0, 0),
                 var.g = c(83.2, 53.6, 94.9, 80.8, 25.6, 29.2, 31.9, 29.8, 102.3, 83.9, 158.7, 126.6, 78.5, 186.9, 82.4, 62))

PCA1 <- prcomp(ex[ , 2:4], scale = TRUE)

library(ggfortify)
autoplot(PCA1, data = ex, colour = "year", 
         loadings.label = T,  frame.colour="treat.year", frame=T)+theme(legend.position = "none")
```